# Loading unnamespaced classes using composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have the following structure

```
application:
    controllers:
        - SomeController.php
        - SomeOtherController.php

public:
    - index.php
```

I am including certain packages using composer. I would like to find a way to autoload my controllers using composer. However, my controllers are not namespaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases when your project structure doesn't follow PSR-0 or PSR-4 standard, you can define a class map that could look like so:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["application/controllers/"]
    }
}
```

It will scan the given directories and files for files with `.php` or `.inc` extensions and load them.
You can read more about composer class maps [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap).